# ios file is not being saved

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the following code; however my file does not get saved inside `/tmp` folder, I think it's because my dylib is Sandboxed which would explain why the log file isn't being created or written because I may not have permissions to do so. Correct me if I'm wrong.

How would I fix this issue?

```
@interface logTool: NSObject
    + (void)logDataFromNSString: (NSString *)logContent;
    @end

@implementation logTool

+ (void)logDataFromNSString: (NSString *)logContent
{

    NSFileHandle *file;
    NSData *data;

    file = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath: @"/tmp/filelog.txt"];

    [file seekToEndOfFile];

    logContent = [logContent stringByAppendingString:@"\n------------\n"];
    data = [logContent dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [file writeData: data];

    [file closeFile];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

It isn't allowed to write to `/tmp` in iOS. You should construct the file path with `NSTemporaryDirectory`instead:

```
NSString *path = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"filelog.txt"];

file = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:path];
```

Comment: What directory does that file get saved in?

Comment: It's not inside /tmp folder @clemens

Comment: This directory is located in the Sandbox of your app. The exact path depends on the App. You can't write to the App, because iOS doesn't allows that. You have only access to the Sandbox.

Comment: Sorry, I'm fairly new to this entire thing. So where is Sandbox located? I can ssh into it from my PC? or should I use ifile in my phone.

Comment: The Sandbox is an individual folder for the App on the device. It contains several folders where your App has the permission to read from or to write to. You cannot write to other folders on your device.

Comment: So using the method you showed; it gets saved into the Sandbox specified app folder that has read/write permission, right?

Comment: Also; do you know where those Sandbox individual folder might be located? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, this is a temporary folder only for your App, and no, the exact path for this folder depends from your App. You can use debugger or `NSLog`to get it's location, but your App shouldn't rely on that, because it's not guaranteed that this path is "constant". Why you're interested in?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165261/discussion-between-dilli-and-clemens).